# Proving that $x^5 = x \pmod{10}$ for every integer $x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Show that  $x^5 = x \pmod{10}$ for every integer $x$.

How can I approach this? Should I use induction? I am stuck trying to get it in terms of $x+1$.

Some feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Induction is unnecessary. You just have to check it for the ten different cases.

Comment: It's hard to give feedback when you haven't provided us with any of your own working, I'm afraid. Please show what you've done so far :)

Comment: Well I tried to get an implication P(n) => P(n+1) but then I realized these aren't natural numbers... I got lost afterwards so there isn't much I could post.

Comment: As @Arthur said, you can brute force this very easily. Even more easy if you have access to a computer: http://repl.it/8mu

Answer (score 5):

We are to prove that $x^5-x$ is divisible by 10.

Also $x^5-x=x(x^4-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$, therefore it is the product of two consecutive numbers, $x(x-1)$, hence divisible by $2$.(recall product of $r$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $r!$)

also, $n^p-n$ is divisible by a prime $p$ ([Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)). Plug $p=5$ to show it is divisible by $5$.

since it is divisible by $2$ and $5$ hence is divisible by $10$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an induction proof, since that's what you're trying to do. The base case is $1^5\equiv 1$, which is obvious.

Assume $n^5\equiv n$. Now we have
$$
(n+1)^5=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1\\
\equiv n + 1+5(n^4+n) +10(n^3+n^2)\\
\equiv n+1+5n(n^3+1)\\
\equiv n+1
$$
We have $5n(n^3+1)\equiv 0$ since it's $5$ times an odd number times an even number (either $n$ or $n^3+1$ is always even).

Thus the result follows.

Comment: Just a comment for the OP, but this is also how the induction proceeds with Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You could check this by brute force. There are only ten cases to check. For instance:
$$0^5 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
$$1^5 \equiv 1 \mod 10$$
$$2^5 = 32 \equiv 2 \mod 10$$
$$3^5 = 243 \equiv 3 \mod 10$$
$$4^5 = 1024 \equiv 4 \mod 10$$
etc.

It's not a slick way to prove it, but it works if you can't think of anything else.

Comment: And you can stop at $x=5$ because $-x \equiv 10-x $ for $6\le x < 9$ and $(-x)^5 = -x^5$.

Comment: @lhf Yes. That is a great point.

Answer (score 1):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),
$$x^5\equiv x\pmod 5$$
But $x^5\equiv x\pmod 2$ is obvious by checking the even/odd case, therefore
$$x^5\equiv x\pmod{10}$$